# SAP HANA Smart Data Integration

Tags: hana, sdi

I'm fairly new to HANA's SDI functionality. Essentially I am trying to create a flow graph that will copy data from a virtual table to a physical table. I can set my data source as the virtual table, however when I try to set the physical table as my target, nothing appears. I am essentially doing this from within a HDI Container while the physical table is sitting in a tenant DB.

Same server and schema though.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access tables that are not part of the HDI container from within an HDI container it's necessary to create *synonyms* to those tables.

There is what feels like a *metric ton* of documentation and tutorials available on just this point.

Examples:

- [Synonyms in HANA XS Advanced, Introduction](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/01/06/synonyms-in-hana-xs-advanced-introduction/)
- [Enable Access to Objects in a Remote Classic Schema](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4505d0bdaf4948449b7f7379d24d0f0d/2.0.04/en-US/402944b21b7c4d60a825b3ac69479955.html)

Once the synonym to the target table is correctly set up for your HDI container, you should be able to "see" it in SDI.
Be aware that the account that is used for the synonym definition needs to be able to write to the target table, otherwise your data loading won't work.